# ASP.Net Validation remove < >

Tags: asp.net, regex

Does anyone know how to set a regular expression validator to not allow the characters < and > because when typing < a >  (without spaces) for example i recieve an error.  I would like to keep the page validation enabled ideally, and there should never be any html input.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: you mean this `^[^<>]+$` ?

Comment: Are you sure you also want to exclude greater than and lower than signs? Have you tried anything? Please show your code.

Comment: That is perfect! thank you very much for your reply, i had tried a few examples for removing special characters but they fired for full stops etc.  Its more to prevent someone trying to exceute a < script > function without erroring really